# Using Someone Else's Github Code

Tags: github

I've been learning about forking, but haven't seen precisely my question answered.  I'd like to use someone else's code in my own project.  I do not want to submit a pull or change anything in the main branch, but instead start my own using someone else's code as a starting point.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Fork the original (other's) repo. Then clone your own/forked repo locally. Change | Commit | Push to your own repo.

Comment: Is the fork necessary, or can you straight up clone/download the zip?  Forking doesn't seem to do anything in my browser, must it be done in the desktop app?  Also, how do I include credit, or is that already included implicitly through the clone?

Comment: You can clone/download zip directly. I'm not sure what do you mean by `credit`?

Comment: Reference to the original writer of the code

Comment: It's automatically maintained by Git (clone/download). `.git` folder exist in the repo.